# Why doesn't fopen open existing file? (returns NULL, errno ENOENT)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fopen

**I have posted this to document my issue, see my self-answer below.**

No matter what I try, `fopen(...)` cannot open the *existing* file at the path which exists and returns `NULL`. ***I am executing the program from a bash script in `~/path`. The program file is stored at `~/path/to`.***

```
int main(void) {
  const char* filename = "my/file"
  FILE* fp = NULL;
  fp = fopen(filename, "r"); // file is still NULL, segfaults on indirection
  if (!fp) exit(1);
  fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: have you tried using an absolute path - to negate changes to working directory. in order to debug the issue you can open the file with `w+` and then search the file system to know how your path is interperted. a good idea is to also verify correct permissions to the file and its path

Comment: Your main bug is to not handle failure of `fopen`. You always need to handle that!

Comment: Note that the file path name is evaluated relative to the current directory of the process, which is unrelated to the directory where the program is stored on disk.  The file clearly does not exist `./path/to/my/file` — it may exist at `$(dirname $(which program))/path/to/my/file`, but that's quite different.

Comment: No, I am trying to teach you good practices... There are very few cases where an `fopen` should not be checked against failure.

Comment: Of course I was handling in the production code. The toy program is just a prop for the question.

Comment: Then you should have told that in your question, and  `perror` would have given you some clue; the actual value of `errno` is useful! BTW `exit(-1)` is wrong (should be `exit(1)` or `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`)

Comment: Because [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) and [_exit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) recommends that. The argument to `exit` is expected to be some 8 bits unsigned number in practice (at least on Linux), and `EXIT_FAILURE` is defined according to the C11 standard

Answer (score 4):

[fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) is documented as capable of failing:

> Otherwise, NULL is returned and `errno` is set to indicate the error.

So you should at least code:

```
FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
if (fp == NULL) { perror(filename); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

and `fopen`  won't even try to *create* a file that you open for reading only.

As a rule of thumb, **you *always* need to check against failure of `fopen`** (a minima like above), and report to your user (with the help of [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html), [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) -used as `strerror(errno)`- ...) the reason of that failure. An educated user would be able to manage (perhaps with help from his sysadmin).

`ENOENT` is documented in [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) to mean

> `ENOENT`          No such file or directory (POSIX.1-2001).
>
> Typically, this error results when a specified path‐
>                          name does not exist, or one of the components in the
>                          directory prefix of a pathname does not exist, or the
>                          specified pathname is a dangling symbolic link.

I find that explanation pretty clear. In your case, you probably don't have any `path/` directory in your current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), or you do have `path/to/my/` directory without any `file` entry, etc (e.g. `path/` exists but without `to/` inside it) ....

You could improve your program by showing not only the `errno` (using `strerror(errno)` or `perror`) but also the working directory. See [getcwd(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html). Or you could leave your user to guess it. Your user could have changed the working directory, e.g. with a `cd` builtin command of his [unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell).

Comment: Next time, read the documentation (including pages like `errno` mentioned in the `man` page of `fopen`)

Comment: Thanks, that is how the issue was diagnosed.

Comment: @nolan.: If this helped select the answer. Anyway plus one for a good answer.

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
_tfopen(filename, _T("r"))
```

Comment: Can you explain how this addresses the problem? Also, if you're using `_tfopen`, then you should enclose and text arguments in `_T(...)`.

Comment: Yes you are right.
_T("...") macro should be used for strings.
This is how I solved my errno:2 problem in my project.
It gave an error that the file does not exist. I used _tfopen instead of fopen, put the strings in the _T("") macro and replaced the 'char' ones with TCHAR.